# ASP.NET cache add vs insert

Tags: asp.net, caching

What is the difference between the `Cache.Add()` and `Cache.Insert()` methods?

In which situations should I use each one?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

`Insert` will overwrite an existing cached value with the same Key; `Add` fails (does nothing) if there is an existing cached value with the same key. So there's a case for saying you should always use Insert since the first time the code runs it will put your object into the cache and when it runs subsequently it will update the cached value.

Comment: Do you think Add method is totally useless?

Comment: @guchko-gleb Not if your use for the Cache should never encounter an existing cached value at a given step in your code - then the Exception from Add would be welcome.

Comment: Side note: Add does not raise an exception if the item already exists according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/18c1wd61(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

`Cache.Add()` also returns a cached object from `Cache` after it was added:

```
string cachedItem = Cache.Add("cachedItem", ....);
```

Comment: Add returns the *existing value* in the cache: if you are adding a new item, it returns null.  If you attempt to overwrite an existing value, nothing happens and the value in the cache is returned.

Answer (score -3):

You can use either `Cache.Add()` or `Cache.Insert()` methods for caching your data. The only difference between the two is, `Cache.Add()` method returns the object which you want to cache.
So let’s say if you want to use the object and cache it as well. You can do so in a single line of code with the help of `Cache.Add()`.

`Cache.Insert()` methods has 4 different types of overloaded methods while `Cache.Add()` has only one.

Comment: I lost a lot of time today because Cache.Add will not overwrite values that are already in the cache, and does not throw an exception.

Comment: @steve has a **very** important point. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/18c1wd61(v=vs.100).aspx) (emphasis mine): _...if you use the `Add` method and an item with the same name already exists in the cache, the method **will not** replace the item and **will not** raise an exception._

Comment: Add returns the *existing value* in the cache: if you are adding a new item, it returns null.  If you attempt to overwrite an existing value, nothing happens and the value in the cache is returned.