# HttpContext.Cache Add vs Insert and Session

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, caching

Basically I know what the difference is. Also, I do know (as you all) there is a lot of resources discussing the issue (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6485463/asp-net-cache-add-vs-insert)).

But today, I heard an strange and weird idea which says `Add` method, adds the object to application-scope cache, while the `Insert` method will adds the object to the session-scope cache!!!

I mean `HttpContext.Current.Cache.Add` will add object to a shared memory which is accessible for all users/threads/sessions/requests/etc.
But `HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert` will add the object to a session-dependent cache (which actually would be the session itself. right? :D)!!!

It's the first time I'm hearing such a thing. I did search the msdn and technet.microsoft.com. I also did decompile the `Cache` class (via dear ReSharper) and read the entire code (and it's dependencies). But nothing came out which make a dependency between Cache and Session.

I'm just asking. Is there any relationship between Cache and Session?

Note: The app is running on a web garden in a Win 2012 R2 machine with IIS 8.5.

Answer (score 1):

There are separate and in a different scope to each other.

As far as I can see, both Methods are applicable to the Cache object and calling `Add` will not have any interaction with the Session object

Comment: I would agree that I cannot find any reference to that being the case.